# Makefile what is "SHELL = bash"

Tags: makefile

I'm newbie with shell script.

I saw some shell script code here https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile

I just want to know what does it mean~

> SHELL = bash

please let me know where the documentation is.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Basics

Comment: Makefiles are not shell scripts. Correcting title and tagging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you saw isn't a shell script, but a Makefile.

`SHELL` is the Makefile variable that sets the preferred shell to use. The default on is `/bin/sh`, so if you need Bash features, you might have to set this variable.

[Documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html).

If it was a shell-script, SHELL would be an environment variable that points to the the user's default shell.

Comment: now i know, makefile is different with shell script~ thank you :)

Comment: SHELL does *not* point to the currently running shell. It is an environment variable that tells other programs which shell you prefer, so they will use that if a shell is needed.  Run csh and echo $SHELL.  Then run ksh and echo $SHELL.  If it is different, it's only because your startup scripts are changing it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That could definitely be true for other shells. Because I use Bash, my understanding of it is as Bash defines - "SHELL  The full pathname to the shell is kept in this environment variable. If it is not set when the shell starts, bash assigns to it the full pathname of the current user's login shell."

Comment: Which just means that bash sets SHELL if you fail to do so, assuming that you want bash to be the default.  It is a source of many errors for people to assume that the setting of SHELL is necessarily related to the currently running shell.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I should have stressed the first part: "The full pathname to the shell is kept in this environment variable." I get it that its the default shell associated with the user account. I've updated my answer to be more precise about that.

Comment: "points to the the user's default shell"  is incorrect.  It is an environment variable that describes the user's preferred shell.